# Cherrypy: Where should I keep my templates

Tags: templates, python-3.x, cherrypy

I'm trying to use jinja2 as the template lib for cherrypy.
I'm unable to figure out where should I keep my template files.

The way I'm using it is as documented here:
http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/choosingtemplate.html#id2

Can we indicate the path in config file? If yes, what should be the key under which config should be put? Or is it relative to the directory from where app (the file with quickstart call) is invoke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CherryPy does not tell you where to put your templates, but you can add the location to a config file (under whatever heading you like) and supply it to FileSystemLoader manually.

If you follow the guide you linked to, your templates should be located in a 'templates' folder in the directory you are running the server from.

(N.B. I use pystache, not Jinja, but the principle is the same)